# Epsilon delta representation of sum of partial derivaticves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function. Can we write
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y+\epsilon)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}
$$

We have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}$$
And
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lim_{\epsilon_1 \to 0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y+\epsilon_1)-f(x,y)}
{\epsilon_1}
$$

How do I combine this to get the above equation. In particular how do I deal with $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $f$ is differentiable, the directional derivative can be obtained by an inner product:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{v}} = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{v}
$$
if you take $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}=(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)$ you get the result.

In particular
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{v}}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y+\epsilon)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}\\
&\nabla f \cdot \mathbf{v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{align}